# Conditionally show Vue component

Tags: vue.js

How do I conditionally show this component if the categories array passed in is empty?

**Parent**

```
<map
    :products="{{ markers |json_encode }}"
    :categories="{{ categories |json_encode }}"
/>
```

**Map**

```
<script>
import Filter from './Filter.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        Filter
    },

    props: {
        categories: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

I thought all it'd need would be `v-if="categories"` but that doesn't do it. The component still shows when no categories exist.

I've also tried `v-if="categories.length > 0"` which does hide the component but keeps it hidden even if there are categories.

Comment: an empty array is still considered [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript.  you need a more specific check, e.g. `v-if="categories.length > 0"`

Comment: Your recent edit suggests that `categories` is not reactive. Where does it come from and how is it updated?

Comment: I've added the parent component which passes the categories array in.